# Authenticate with Azure Artifacts from Dockerfile for Java(Maven), NPM

Tags: docker, maven, npm, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Can some one please provide what is the recommended solution for authenticating inside Dockerfile during docker build phase for Azure Artifacts for **Maven**, **NPM** or **Python**?

While most of the solutions for the particular problem of accessing authenticated feed of Azure Artifacts while building from inside a Dockerfile has been mentioned on Stack Overflow or on the internet (in various articles such as below) have targeted the nuget ecosystem, my question is for *Maven*, *NPM* or *Python* Packages.

Example blogs that provide solutions for nuget & docker-

- https://blog.ehn.nu/2019/05/accessing-azure-artifacts-feed-in-a-docker-build/

Appreciate the help here.

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is for Maven, NPM or Python Packages.

These package types are from different systems, so we should use different ways to authenticate them.

**For Maven:**

Check [set-up-your-feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/maven?view=azure-devops#set-up-your-feed)
. You should configure your `pom.xml` file to define the url, and then define `settings.xml` file with PAT. You can manage these two files in your project, then use Dockerfile to copy the `settings.xml` to `${user.home}/.m2` folder.

**For NPM:**

[image]

You can follow `Other` topic here to configure one `.npmrc` which contains credentials. Also I think you can create a normal `.npmrc` file, and then use `Npm Authenticate task` to modify it. Here's one [working sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52317396/10910450).

**For Python:**

We can use the [Pip Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/pip-authenticate?view=azure-devops) to populates the `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` environment variable and pass it as build arguments. Something like this: `arguments: --build-arg INDEX_URL=$(PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL)`

You can check the two answers from [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099159/azure-devops-install-python-package-from-azure-artifacts-inside-docker) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @lance Li-MSFT, so looks like only way to get this encapsulated is to create a temporary settings.xml or npmrc files (where the secrets or tokens get replaced at run time during build) and once build is completed we can discard it using a multi stage build. Am I correct ?

Comment: @BB8 Yes. And once the packages has restored and the real build has finished, we can add a `delete` step to delete the temporary file.

Comment: Thanks @lance Li-MSFT